# Create polyline with multiple marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I would like to ask about suggestion on creating polyline with multiple marker? How can I solve the solution about this? I already create but sadly I created hard code. **What i want to do is get coordinate from firebase then draw polyline on the map.** Is there any solution on drawing the route using polyline?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K5yy.png) [here how i want to get coordinate from firebase.]

Comment: You said you "already create". But isn't the only way to draw route is using polyline?

Comment: yes, but im stuck on drawing using marker from firebase. I have problem on writing to draw the polyline to get coordinate from database.

Comment: sory if i have broken language.

Comment: Is marker coordinate the only thing you have? No polyline data? Do you want to draw straight lines or road lines.

Comment: Yes i only have marker coordinate. no polyline data. i want straight line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw `polyline` with `LatLng`.

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
// add coordinates to polyline
for (LatLng markerCoordinate : markerCoordinates) {
    polylineOptions.add(markerCoordinate);
}

// draw
googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. can you help me on retrieve the coordinate from firebase?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var marker = "";
          // This info Window is used to show data
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
         // get data from firebase ann passed it to CreatePolyline function
      function CreatePolyline(data) {   
        // Convert you lat long to gmap coordinate                      
            var coordinates = [];
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var lat = parseFloat(data[i].Lattitude);
                var long = parseFloat(data[i].Longitude);
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                coordinates.push(point);
            }
            // this loop is used to place marker on your lat long
            for (i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {

                var positions = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i]);
                if (i == 0) {
                    //start location
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: positions,
                    map: map,
                    icon: "green.png",                      
                    data: data[i] 
                });
                }
                else if (i == coordinates.length - 1) {
                        // End Location
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: positions,
                        map: map,
                        icon: "redicon.png",                           
                        data: data[i]
                    });

                }
                else {
                       // In between Location
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: positions,
                        map: map,
                        icon: "blueicon.png",                            
                        data: data[i]
                    });
                }
                // Info Window Design
                var content = "<b>Employee Code: </b>" + data[i].EmployeeCode + "<br /><b>Date: </b>" + data[i].Date + "<br /><b>Location: </b>" + data[i].Location + "<br/> <b>Battery Level: </b>" + data[i].BatteryLevel;  
                 // To handle marker click Event                  
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content, infowindow) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    };
                })(marker, content, infowindow));

            }

            //Create the polyline that connects the markers.
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: coordinates,
                stroke: {
                           color: '#ffffff',
                           weight: 5
                       },
                       editable: false,
                       draggable: false,
                       geodesic: true,
                       visible: true,
                       icons: [
                         {
                             icon: {
                                 path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
                             },
                             offset: '50px',
                             repeat: '50px'
                         }
                       ]
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
        }

        
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      
        function onItemClick(event, pin) {              
            var contentString = "<b>Employee Code: </b>" + pin.data.EmployeeCode + "<br /><b>Date: </b>" + pin.data.Date + "<br /><b>Location: </b>" + pin.data.Location + "<br/> <b>Battery Level: </b>" + pin.data.BatteryLevel;
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);    
                infowindow.open(map,marker) 
            }
```